# Instantiation error when comparing two different values

Tags: comparison, prolog, instantiation

I've got a predicate that looks like the following:

```
    condition_met([(X + 1) < 5 | Rest]) :- condition_met(Rest),
                                           at(X,_),
                                           write('X = '),
                                           write(X),
                                           Temp is (X + 1),
                                           Temp < 5, !.
```

`at(X,Y)` is something I assert before running the query. when I assert the two values to be number that would make the query true, it runs fine. But as soon as I assert X to be something greater than 4, I get an instantiation error on (<). I don't understand why it wouldn't just return no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found my problem, sort of. I'm still not sure why it's happening, but I had a bad understanding of how labels work. I've found a way to get the answer I want out of the predicate.